# Convexity wrt a matrix, convexity wrt vectors

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If a function $f(X)$ is a convex function of matrix $X$, does it imply that $f$ is also a convex function of all rows of $X$?
(My final goal is to see if I can use coordinate descent by optimizing a convex objective wrt to each row of the matrix, and iterate until convergence to get to a global solution)

Comment: Excuse me, but what in the world does a function "being convex on a matrix" mean? What are the domain and the range of that function?

Comment: Sorry, I edited that. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Still confused: if the function $\;f\;$ has matrices as argument (i.e., it is defined *on matrices*), how could it then be defined on rows/columns? Unless it is a function that is defined on matrices of *any* size and then we can look at a matrix's rows as $\,1\times n\;$ matrices, but this is weird...

Comment: In the latter situation, the function is still defined on same matrix $X$, but only one row of the matrix considered as variable, the other rows are fixed.

Comment: I still can't parse that, @user25004 . Why don't you better tell us what is the domain of $\;f\;$ and its range?

Comment: An example can be $f(X) = trace(X'AX)$, where $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an (confirmatory) answer for the following precision of the question. Then the OP can decide if that is what he meant.

Let
$$
  f \colon  D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
be a convex function where $ D \subset \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a convex function from some convex subset of the set of all real $m\times n$-matrices into 
$\mathbb{R}$.  We can look upon $f$ as a function of $m$ arguments, being the first, second, etc, ... $m$th row of the argument matrix $X$. We can fix the second, third, ... $m$th argument, and look upon this as only a function of the first argument. Let that define a function $f_1 \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is defined on the convex set $D_1(x_{20},\dots,x_{m0}) = \{ 
y\in \mathbb{R}^n \colon  \begin{pmatrix} y^T \\ x_{20}^T \\ \vdots \\ x_{m0}^T \end{pmatrix} \in D \}$, which is known to be convex for each selection of fixed vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_{20}, \dots, x_{m0}$. $f_1$ is given simply by
$$
  f_1(y) = f( \begin{pmatrix} y^T \\ x_{20}^T \\ \vdots \\ x_{m0}^T \end{pmatrix}
$$
where the dependence on the selected, fixed  vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_{20}, \dots, x_{m0}$ is implicit. Define $f_2, \dots, f_m$ analogously.

Now it is an easy exercise to show that each $f_i$ is convex, and that I will leave for the original poster.